# Comparar preços levando em consideração as unidades (kg, g)

Tags: java, android

Olá, preciso comparar 2 produtos, levando em consideração o peso deles e os valores, para saber qual produto é mais vantajoso comprar.

Ex: 
Arroz 5kg - R$ 10,00
Arroz 2kg - R$ 6,00

Pensando que pode comparar gramas com kg, fazendo a conversão correta.
Sou iniciante em programação pra Android e ficarei muito agradecida pela ajuda.

A parte de layout eu já entendo bem, preciso mesmo é da parte da MainActivity.
Na imagem mostra mais ou menos como vai ficar no final.

Não estou sabendo fazer esse cálculo. Como verifico se a unidade escolhida é 'g' ou 'kg', 'l', 'ml' e como fazer o calculo baseado na conversão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Activity está assim no momento, lembrando que estou iniciando em desenvolvimento mobile e estou gostando muito.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v) {

            //unidades
            Spinner peso1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            Spinner peso2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

            //quantidade em unidades
            EditText qtd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtd1);
            EditText qtd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtd2);

            //valor do produto
            EditText valor1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valor1);
            EditText valor2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valor2);

            Double resultado1;
            Double resultado2;

            Double vlr1 = Double.parseDouble(valor1.getText().toString());
            Double vlr2 = Double.parseDouble(valor2.getText().toString());

            Integer quantidade1 = Integer.parseInt(qtd1.getText().toString());
            Integer quantidade2 = Integer.parseInt(qtd2.getText().toString());

            //deve fazer as conversão para o cálculo
            if (peso1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("g"){
                quantidade1 = quantidade1 * 0.001; //converte pra kg

            }
            if (peso2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("g"){
                quantidade2 = quantidade2 * 0.001;/ //converte pra kg

            }

            resultado1 = quantidade1 * vlr1;
            resultado2 = quantidade2 * vlr2;


            if (quantidade1 > quantidade2 || resultado1 < resultado2) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Compre o produto tal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (quantidade1 < quantidade2 || resultado1 > resultado2) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Compre o produto tal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A vantagem dos produtos é a mesma", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (quantidade1 == quantidade2){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mesma quantidade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Poste o codigo da `Activity` que vc possui, ajuda a contextualizar e facilita na construção da resposta.

Comment: A dificuldade é no cálculo ou em obter os valores do formulário?

Comment: Sim, minha dificuldade é entender como é feito esse cálculo tendo em vista os valores informados.

Comment: @FláviaAmaral olhando assim parece que você fez o algoritmo correto. Você teve algum erro? Onde exatamente é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Não estou sabendo fazer esse cálculo. Como verifico se a unidade escolhida é 'g' ou 'kg', 'l', 'ml' e como fazer o calculo baseado na conversão.

Comment: @FláviaAmaral você já fez isso aqui: `if(peso1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("g")){quantidade1 = quantidade1 * 0.001;}`

Comment: Já, já sim. Está aí no códigos acima. Será que estou fazendo certo e nem eu sei? Rs

Comment: @FláviaAmaral acredito que vc já resolveu o problema sim :) a não ser pelo fato que faltou um parenteses antes da chave, mas se for isso seu código nem compilaria. Repare no meu comentário ali em cima tem `))` depois do equals.

Comment: A conversão de L/mL pra kg/g seria um pouco mais complicada. Você não tem como calcular sem saber a densidade do produto. 1 litro de água pesa 1kg, mas 1 litro de outra coisa pode pesar mais, ou menos, que isso.

Comment: vc pode ver o calculo em rotasul.net/tools/comparador.php por sinal eu utilizo sempre essa pagina, mesmo offline []'s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É possível fazer isso usando uma abordagem Orientada a Objetos para encapsular a complexidade dessas contas.

## Construindo um modelo de Produto

Primeiro você pode criar um `Enum` para cada escala de medida.

Por exemplo, para peso:

```java
public enum UnidadePeso implements UnidadeProporcional {
    Grama(1), Kilograma(1000), Tonelada(1000000);

    private int proporcao;

    private UnidadePeso(int proporcao) {
        this.proporcao = proporcao;
    }

    @Override
    public int proporcao() {
        return proporcao;
    }
}
```

E para volume:

```java
public enum UnidadeVolume implements UnidadeProporcional {
    Mililitro(1), Litro(1000);

    private int proporcao;

    private UnidadeVolume(int proporcao) {
        this.proporcao = proporcao;
    }

    @Override
    public int proporcao() {
        return proporcao;
    }
}
```

A interface `UnidadeProporcional` serve para generalizar o método `proporcao()`:

```java
public interface UnidadeProporcional {

    int proporcao();

}
```

Finalmente, aqui está uma classe genérica de `Produto` que recebe o valor unitário, a quantidade e a unidade de medida e permite a comparação entre si:

```java
public class Produto<T extends UnidadeProporcional> implements Comparable<Produto<T>> {

    private BigDecimal preco;
    private int quantidade;
    private T unidade;

    public Produto(BigDecimal preco, int quantidade, T unidade) {
        if (preco == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Preço nulo!");
        }
        if (quantidade <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantidade deve ser um inteiro positivo!");
        }
        if (unidade == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Informe a unidade!");
        }
        this.preco = preco;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.unidade = unidade;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna o preço na unidade básica para possibilitar a comparação em unidades diferentes.
     * Por exemplo, se a unidade for kg, o "preço base" será dividido por 1000, ou seja, o valor em gramas do produto.
     * Além disso, o resultado também será dividido pela quantidade, de forma que o resultado seja o valor por grama. 
     */
    public BigDecimal getPrecoBase() {
        return preco.divide(new BigDecimal(unidade.proporcao())).divide(new BigDecimal(quantidade));
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public T getUnidade() {
        return unidade;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Produto<T> o) {
        if (o == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Objeto nulo!");
        }
        return this.getPrecoBase().compareTo(o.getPrecoBase());
    }

}
```

O método `getPrecoBase()` faz a "mágica", retornando o preço do produto na unidade básica da escala.

Por exemplo, se a unidade do produto for `Kg` e a quantidade 2, ele dividir o valor por 1000 para transformar a unidade em gramas e dpeois por 2 para obter o valor de uma grama.

Logo, ele normaliza os valores possibilitar a comparação.

## Exemplo de uso

Com o modelo contruído, você pode simplesmente criar dois produtos e compará-los:

```java
Produto<UnidadePeso> laranjaExtra = new Produto<UnidadePeso>(
    new BigDecimal("50"), 1, UnidadePeso.Kilograma);

Produto<UnidadePeso> laranjaCarrefour = new Produto<UnidadePeso>(
    new BigDecimal("49.95"), 1000, UnidadePeso.Grama);

int resultado = laranjaExtra.compareTo(laranjaCarrefour);
```

Se você já comparou objetos em Java com o método `compareTo` deve saber que um retorno `0` significa que os valores são iguais, `1` que o primeiro é maior que o segundo e `-1` para o contrário.

O código acima vai retornar `1` porque o valor por grama da laranja no Extra sai por `R$ 0,05`, enquanto no Carrefour sai por `R$ 0,04995`.

## Melhore o meu código

Você pode baixar ou clonar o projeto com o código acima no meu [Github](https://github.com/utluiz/java-playground/tree/master/random-code/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/comparadorpreco).

Você pode incrementá-lo, por exemplo, para receber uma quantidade do tipo `BigDecimal`, já que o usuário pode entrar com `1,5` litros ou kilogramas.